# Suddenly AppSettings becomes empty in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, configurationmanager, appsettings

I have a some asp.net mvc app, and web.config (all locations default)
Suddenly `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` collection becomes empty, and i can't see any values from `Web.config` here.
Why that can happen?

[image]

Comment: Have you recently published the site?

Comment: No, i am working on localhost, using IIS

Comment: It seems that app not see web.config at all, all other libraries also can't read data from it. But if i do some changes in Web.config f.e. edit it so it becomes not valid xml, then app not building.